# Why should I use Rails HTTP status symbols instead of codes? Or, why not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-status-codes

E.g. `:ok` over `200` (or viceversa) for [HTTP responses](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option).

Advantages and disadvantages, pros and cons, etc. of using symbols instead of codes (or viceversa) are welcome.

Comment: Do you remember every status code by heart? Is it nicer to read 407 or proxy_authentication_required? In any case it’s an opinion thing

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I think that's not enough to justify the use of symbols. There must be something more...

Comment: This question seems like it will lead to an opinion-based solution. The [`documentation`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option) mentions that Rails understands both numeric status codes and the written symbols, but does not address a preference.

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby follows convention of Human Readable Code